# R - remove duplicated rows by subtraction of the means

Tags: r

I have a large gene expression data frame with duplicated genes that represents two groups (control and disease). For the duplicated genes, I need to select only one, based on the subtraction of the mean value of the control group vs the mean value of the disease group (same row). In that case, i must select the gene with the largest substraction result.

Here is a small example of my dataframe:

```
 GENES=c("7A5", "A1BG", "A1BG", "A1BG","AAAS","AAAS", "AFDS","AFDS","AFDS")
 Control1 = c(2.1471840, -0.9092227, -1.4875100, -2.79559765,  0.05143231, -1.25764808,  0.6104962,  0.09226673, -0.8037355)
 Control2 = c(-0.3709474,  1.4587290,  1.4545832, -0.27379895, -0.45116476,  1.56286706, -0.9225275, -0.54779659, -1.0586287)
 Control3 = c(-1.1321667, -1.3051079, -0.9658358, -0.05914144, -0.20133056,  0.03029207,  1.0015907,  1.18145151,  0.5360956)
 Disease1 = c(0.6824169,  0.1645328,  2.6276603,  1.11739548, -1.13592005, -0.12666909, -0.4667365, -0.80153098, -1.1085319)
 Disease2 = c(1.1014914, -1.4461279,  1.0965057, -1.58379531, -0.12457328,  0.59232328,  0.2319656,  0.46981373, -0.4540254)

df=data.frame(GENES,Control1,Control2,Control3,Disease1,Disease2)

> df
  GENES    Control1   Control2    Control3   Disease1   Disease2
1   7A5  2.14718400 -0.3709474 -1.13216670  0.6824169  1.1014914
2  A1BG -0.90922270  1.4587290 -1.30510790  0.1645328 -1.4461279
3  A1BG -1.48751000  1.4545832 -0.96583580  2.6276603  1.0965057
4  A1BG -2.79559765 -0.2737989 -0.05914144  1.1173955 -1.5837953
5  AAAS  0.05143231 -0.4511648 -0.20133056 -1.1359200 -0.1245733
6  AAAS -1.25764808  1.5628671  0.03029207 -0.1266691  0.5923233
7  AFDS  0.61049620 -0.9225275  1.00159070 -0.4667365  0.2319656
8  AFDS  0.09226673 -0.5477966  1.18145151 -0.8015310  0.4698137
9  AFDS -0.80373550 -1.0586287  0.53609560 -1.1085319 -0.4540254
```

In other words, if we use as exemple the gene A1BG, row 3, i need to:

```
mean(col2,col3,col4) - mean(col5,col6) = ?
```

Make the same for the row 4 and row 5 (A1BG duplicates), and choose the A1BG result with the largest difference value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with dplyr like so:

```
new.df <- df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(difference = (mean(c(Control1, Control2, Control3)) - mean(c(Disease1, Disease2))))
```

... gives you the rowwise difference in column means:

```
#    GENES    Control1   Control2    Control3   Disease1   Disease2   Difference
#   <fctr>       <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1    7A5  2.14718400 -0.3709474 -1.13216670  0.6824169  1.1014914 -0.6772642
# 2   A1BG -0.90922270  1.4587290 -1.30510790  0.1645328 -1.4461279  0.3889303
# 3   A1BG -1.48751000  1.4545832 -0.96583580  2.6276603  1.0965057 -2.1950039
# 4   A1BG -2.79559765 -0.2737989 -0.05914144  1.1173955 -1.5837953 -0.8096461
# 5   AAAS  0.05143231 -0.4511648 -0.20133056 -1.1359200 -0.1245733  0.4298923
# 6   AAAS -1.25764808  1.5628671  0.03029207 -0.1266691  0.5923233 -0.1209901
# 7   AFDS  0.61049620 -0.9225275  1.00159070 -0.4667365  0.2319656  0.3472386
# 8   AFDS  0.09226673 -0.5477966  1.18145151 -0.8015310  0.4698137  0.4078325
# 9   AFDS -0.80373550 -1.0586287  0.53609560 -1.1085319 -0.4540254  0.3391891
```

You can use these values to select the maximum row in each "GENES" group  by un-grouping, re-grouping by "GENES", and slicing the row with the maximum "Difference value:

```
new.df %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(GENES) %>% 
  slice(which.max(Difference))

#    GENES    Control1   Control2   Control3   Disease1   Disease2   Difference
#   <fctr>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1    7A5  2.14718400 -0.3709474 -1.1321667  0.6824169  1.1014914 -0.6772642
# 2   A1BG -0.90922270  1.4587290 -1.3051079  0.1645328 -1.4461279  0.3889303
# 3   AAAS  0.05143231 -0.4511648 -0.2013306 -1.1359200 -0.1245733  0.4298923
# 4   AFDS  0.09226673 -0.5477966  1.1814515 -0.8015310  0.4698137  0.4078325
```

Here is another, shorter approach using data.table:

```
setDT(df)[, 
  Difference := (mean(c(Control1, Control2, Control3)) - mean(c(Disease1, Disease2))), 
  by=1:nrow(df)
][, .SD[which.max(Difference)], .(GENES)]

#    GENES    Control1   Control2   Control3   Disease1   Disease2 Difference
# 1:   7A5  2.14718400 -0.3709474 -1.1321667  0.6824169  1.1014914 -0.6772642
# 2:  A1BG -0.90922270  1.4587290 -1.3051079  0.1645328 -1.4461279  0.3889303
# 3:  AAAS  0.05143231 -0.4511648 -0.2013306 -1.1359200 -0.1245733  0.4298923
# 4:  AFDS  0.09226673 -0.5477966  1.1814515 -0.8015310  0.4698137  0.4078325
```

The data.table solution can be a bit harder to read if you're not already familiar with the package, but the expression within the first set of brackets `[ ]` calculates the rowwise difference in means, and then the expression inside the second set of brackets indicates that we want the row with the maximum difference in each group (`.SD[which.max(Difference)`), and then groups by "GENES".

Comment: This should work. May be we can achieve it in one go.

Answer (score 1):

The one possible solution is:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(meanDiff = mean(c(Control1, Control2, Control3)) - mean(c(Disease1, Disease1)) ) %>%
  group_by(GENES) %>%
  filter(meanDiff == max(meanDiff)) %>%
  ungroup()

#Result:
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  GENES  Control1 Control2 Control3 Disease1 Disease2 meanDiff
  <fctr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 7A5      2.15     -0.371   -1.13     0.682    1.10    -0.468
2 A1BG    -0.909     1.46    -1.31     0.165   -1.45    -0.416
3 AAAS     0.0514   -0.451   -0.201   -1.14    -0.125    0.936
4 AFDS     0.0923   -0.548    1.18    -0.802    0.470    1.04
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use base R:

```
rows <- as.logical(ave(rowMeans(df[,c("Control1", "Control2", "Control3")]) - rowMeans(df[,c("Disease1", "Disease2")]), 
                       df$GENES, 
                       FUN = function(x) x == max(x)))
df[rows,]

#  GENES    Control1   Control2   Control3   Disease1   Disease2
#1   7A5  2.14718400 -0.3709474 -1.1321667  0.6824169  1.1014914
#2  A1BG -0.90922270  1.4587290 -1.3051079  0.1645328 -1.4461279
#5  AAAS  0.05143231 -0.4511648 -0.2013306 -1.1359200 -0.1245733
#8  AFDS  0.09226673 -0.5477966  1.1814515 -0.8015310  0.4698137
```